# How to create required UI with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have A Json data from Which I am trying to create a required UI, but my problem is I am facing issue while looping it

**Ui with Static code what I am trying to achieve dynamically**

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: blue;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">



    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card" style="margin: 20px 0">
        <div class="card-header">Employ A</div>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

          <li class="list-group-item">EmployA1 <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success" >
        <span class="slider round" ></span>
      </label>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">EmployA2 <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="card-header">Employ B</div>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

          <li class="list-group-item">EmployB1 <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
          </li>

        </ul>
        <div class="card-header">Employ C</div>

        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">

          <li class="list-group-item">EmployC1 <label class="switch "> <input type="checkbox" class="success">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Dynamic Code I am working on**

```js
var Data = {
  "Employ A": ["EmployA1.jpg", "EmployA2.jpg"],
  "Employ B": ["EmployB1.jpg"],
  "Employ C": ["EmployC1.jpg"]
}

var counters = Object.keys(Data)


console.log(counters.length);
for (var key in Data) {
  ul_innerhtml = "";
  console.log(key)
  $(".card-header").text(key);
  for (i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {

    var ul_innerhtml = ul_innerhtml + '<li class="list-group-item">' + Data + '<label class="switch "><input name="type" type="checkbox" class="success" value="' + Data + '"><span class="slider round"> </span></label></li>';
  }
  $(".list-group").html(ul_innerhtml);
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">


    <div class="card" style="margin: 10px 0">

      <div class="card-header"></div>

      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default commonButton" type="submit">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
  </button>
</div>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, as I am getting gey and trying to show them as in class `.card-header` in div and its values to below the as per check boxes, but it shows up `objext-object` to the values card value is populating correctly but it shows up only one counter

Comment: `Data` is an object, you've to retrieve a value of a property instead of adding an object to the HTML string.

Comment: You need to loop over `Data[counters[i]]`

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. You said you're trying to replicate the static code using the JSON data. But the JSON data doesn't include anything like `Employ A` or `EmployA1`. It has `CounterA1.jpg`, which looks like it should be the source of an `<img>` tag, but there's no tags like that in the code.

Comment: @Barmar sorry my bad i have updated my post please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your nested loop is not correct. It's looping over the same list of keys as `for key in Data`. You need to loop over `Data[key]` to get the array elements.

You need to create a new `card-header` and `list-group` each time through the outer loop, this will contain the employee name. Then the inner loop fills in that list group with the items from the arrays. Finally, you append this all to the `.card` DIV.

```js
var Data = {
  "Employ A": ["EmployA1.jpg", "EmployA2.jpg"],
  "Employ B": ["EmployB1.jpg"],
  "Employ C": ["EmployC1.jpg"]
}

var counters = Object.keys(Data)

console.log(counters.length);
for (var key in Data) {
  var newCard = $(`<div>
      <div class="card-header"></div>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      </ul>
    </div>`);
  var ul_innerhtml = "";
  console.log(key)
  $(".card-header", newCard).text(key);
  Data[key].forEach(d =>
    ul_innerhtml += '<li class="list-group-item">' + d + '<label class="switch "><input name="type" type="checkbox" class="success" value="' + d + '"><span class="slider round"> </span></label></li>'
  )
  $(".list-group", newCard).append(ul_innerhtml);
  $(".card").append(newCard.html());
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  display: none;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="card" style="margin: 10px 0">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn-search" class="btn btn-default commonButton" type="submit">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Go
  </button>
</div>
```